# How to detect if a base 10 decimal can be represented exactly in base 2

Tags: c++

As part of a numerical library test I need to choose base 10 decimal numbers that can be represented exactly in base 2. How do you detect in C++ if a base 10 decimal number can be represented exactly in base 2?

My first guess is as follows:

```
bool canBeRepresentedInBase2(const double &pNumberInBase10)
{
    //check if a number in base 10 can be represented exactly in base 2
    //reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system
    bool funcResult = false;

    int nbOfDoublings = 16*3;
    double doubledNumber = pNumberInBase10;
    for (int i = 0; i < nbOfDoublings ; i++)
    {
        doubledNumber = 2*doubledNumber;
        double intPart;
        double fracPart = modf(doubledNumber/2, &intPart);
        if (fracPart == 0) //number can be represented exactly in base 2
        {
            funcResult = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return funcResult;
}
```

I tested this function with the following values: -1.0/4.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.205, 1.0/3.0, 7.0/8.0, 1.0, 256.0/255.0, 1.02, 99.005. It returns true for -1.0/4.0, 0.0, 7.0/8.0, 1.0, 99.005 which is correct.

Any better ideas?

Comment: Doesn't the repeating decimal issue sort of make this impossible without rounding? And if you are rounding, is this still a valid issue (maybe I'm missing something)

Comment: If you're passing it a double, I guarantee -that- number is being exactly represented in binary.

So I'm not sure I'm getting the exact question.  Do you want to convert the after-decimal part to an int?

Comment: @cmartin: Try this function with 0.1 for example. It will return false. If you input 3/4 it will return true.

Comment: @Samil: that would be true if the argument pNumber were a base-10 type to begin with. Since it's a double, it's already in a binary format (and isn't really storing 0.1).

Comment: I think the original wording of my question was misleading (using the term binary). Now I explicitly state that I am looking for numbers in base 10 that can be represented exactly in base 2. Sorry for that.

Comment: I don't understand. In a computer, all numbers are represented exactly in base 2. Are you trying to determine if the fractional part of a floating point number is zero?

Comment: i don't understand the code's parameter. you pass a double. how can it be in base10 ? it's base2 isn't it?

Comment: @Colin and litb: True, the computer representation is binary. What I mean is that I call the function with base 10 numbers like this: canBeRepresentedInBase2(99.005)

Comment: @Samil: The C++ code "canBeRepresentedInBase2(99.005)" will first convert 99.005 to the closest double that can represent it.  That closest representation is what gets passed to your function.  So, as others have said before me, anything passed to that function is already guaranteed to be base 2.

Comment: You might want to change this back from a wiki since there's a real algorithm that will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a number which has a fractional portion which is the sum of a sequence of negative powers of 2 (aka: 1 over a power of 2). I believe this should always be able to be represented exactly in IEEE floats/doubles.

For example:

0.375 = (1/4 + 1/8) which should have an exact representation.

If you want to generate these. You could try do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    double value = 0.0;
    for(int i = 1; i < 256; i *= 2) {
        // doesn't matter, some random probability of including this
        // fraction in our sequence..
        if((rand() % 3) == 0) {
            value += (1.0 / static_cast<double>(i));        
        }
    }
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

EDIT: I believe your function has a broken interface. It would be better if you had this:

```
bool canBeRepresentedExactly(int numerator, int denominator);
```

because not all fractions have exact representations, but the moment you shove it into a double, you've chosen a representation in binary... defeating the purpose of the test.

Answer (score 4):

If you're checking to see if it's binary, it will always return true.  If your method takes a `double` as the parameter, the number is already represented in binary (`double` is a binary type, usually 64 bits).  Looking at your code, I think you're actually trying to see if it can be represented exactly as an integer, in which case why can't you just cast to `int`, then back to `double` and compare to the original.  Any integer stored in a double that's within the range representable by an `int` should be exact, IIRC, because a 64 bit `double` has 53 bits of mantissa (and I'm assuming a 32 bit int).  That means if they're equal, it's an integer.

Comment: Having looked at the edited question, my answer still stands.  If your method param is a double, it's already in binary (not base 10, no matter what you name the parameter...).

Comment: I agree, I think what he needs to have is something like: bool canBeBinary(int numerator, int denominator); and analyze that, which isn't necessary going to be representable *exactly* in binary.

Comment: @Evan Teran, But that is REALLY easy to test.  return !(denominator & 1);

Comment: strager. hmm, what if we put canBeBinary(3, 10); ? it would say 0.3 can be exactly represented. afaik, it cannot :/ or do i miss something important?

Comment: @strager, yea, that test doesn't work unfortunately because the numerator can be anything (as litb pointed out)

Answer (score 2):

If you're passing in a double, then by definition, it has already been represented in binary and if not, then you've already lost accuracy.

Maybe try passing in numerator and denominator of the fraction to the function. Then you have not lost accuracy and can check to see if you can come up with a binary representation of the answer that is the same as the fraction you've passed in.

Answer (score 1):

As rmeador have pointed out, it might not be a good idea to accept the double, because the number has been converted to a double, an possible approximation to the number that you're trying to check.

So, in a very abstract way, you should split your check into integers, and decimals. Integers should not be too large such that the mantissa cannot express all the integers, (e.g. 9007199254740993 should not be represented properly by a 64-bit fp)
Decimal points may be a bit easier, mentally, because if anything after the decimal point (e.g. yyy in xxx.yyy) contains a factor of anything other than 2, the floating point repeats in order to try to represent it. It's the reason why 1/3 cannot be represented with finite digits in base 10 = base (2*5)... See [Recurring Decimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurring_decimal)

EDIT: As the comments pointed out, if the decimal number has a factor of anything other than 1/2, that would be the mathematically correct way to say it...

Comment: I think you mean to say, if 1/2 isn't one of the number's factors.

Comment: I meant to point out that your statement "the decimal point contains a factor of anything other than 2" should be rewritten.  Otherwise, no such number exists (AFAIK) because the factors of 2 are 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, your method doesn't do what you mean, since you pass a number represented as a (binary) double. The method actually detects, if the number you passed is in the form `integer/2^48`. This should fail for numbers like `(1+2^-50)`, which is binary, and `259/255`, which isn't.

If you really want to test a number for being exactly representable by finite binary string, you have to pass a number in an exact form.

Comment: You are right about the 2^48 limitation. But it correctly detects that 256.0/255.0 cannot be represented in binary.

Comment: Ah, I made a mistake in the number. Try 259/255 instead.

Answer (score 1):

You asked for C++ but maybe this algorithm will help.  I use "EE" to mean "exactly expressible as a float."

Start with a decimal representation of the number you want to test.  Remove any trailing zeroes (that is, 0.123450000 becomes 0.12345).

1)  If the number is not an integer, check to see if the rightmost digit is 5.  If it's not, then stop -- the number is not EE.
2)  Multiply the number by 2.  If the result is an integer, then stop -- the number is EE.  Otherwise, go back to step 1.

I don't have rigorous proof for this but a "warm fuzzy."  Fire up Calculator and enter your favorite fractional power of 2, like 0.0000152587890625.  Add it to itself a few dozen times (I just hit "+" once then "=" a bunch of times).  If there are any non-zero digits to the right of the decimal point, the last digit is always 5.

Comment: Fails on "0.50". Exactly how do you get your input?

Comment: MSalters, thanks.  Forgot to say to remove the trailing zeroes first.  You'd start with "0.5" and the test works then.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass IN a Double because it's already lost precision.  You should be able to use the toString() method of Double to check for this. (example in Java)

```
public static Boolean canBeRepresentedInBase2(String thenumber)
{
    // Reuturns true of the parsed Double did not loose precision.
    // Only works for numbers that are not converted into scientific notation by toString.
    return thenumber.equals(Double.parseDouble(thenumber).toString())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code in C# and it works. Because it works with the Decimal data - there are no inherent rounding errors that show up in the original code which uses double. (decimal in C# stores using base 10 instead of base 2 - which is what double does)

```
static bool canBeRepresentedInBase2(decimal pNumberInBase10)
{
    //check if a number in base 10 can be represented exactly in base 2
    //reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system
    bool funcResult = false;

    int nbOfDoublings = 16*3;
    decimal doubledNumber = pNumberInBase10;
    for (int i = 0; i < nbOfDoublings ; i++)
    {
        doubledNumber = 2*doubledNumber;
        decimal intPart;
        decimal fracPart = ModF(doubledNumber/2, out intPart);
        if (fracPart == 0) //number can be represented exactly in base 2
        {
                funcResult = true;
                break;
        }
    }
    return funcResult;
}

static decimal ModF(decimal number, out decimal intPart)
{
    intPart = Math.Floor(number);
    decimal fractional = number - (intPart);
    return fractional;
}
```

Tested with the following code (where WL does a Console.WritelLine - SnippetCompiler)
WL(canBeRepresentedInBase2(-1.0M/4.0M)); //true
WL(canBeRepresentedInBase2(0.0M)); //true
WL(canBeRepresentedInBase2(0.1M)); //false
WL(canBeRepresentedInBase2(0.2M)); //false
WL(canBeRepresentedInBase2(0.205M)); //false
WL(canBeRepresentedInBase2(1.0M/3.0M)); //false
WL(canBeRepresentedInBase2(7.0M/8.0M)); //true
WL(canBeRepresentedInBase2(1.0M));   //true
WL(canBeRepresentedInBase2(256.0M/255.0M)); //false
WL(canBeRepresentedInBase2(1.02M)); //false
WL(canBeRepresentedInBase2(99.005M)); //false
WL(canBeRepresentedInBase2(2.53M)); //false

Answer (score 0):

Or even easier:

```
return pNumber == floor(pNumber);
```

On the other hand, if you have some  weird fractional representation (numerator denominator pair, or string with a decimal in it, or something), and you really do want to know if the value can be exactly represented as a double, it's a bit harder.

But you would need a different parameter(s) for that...

Comment: If you have the number represented as a fraction, isn't it enough to check that the denominator is a power of two small enough to fit in the mantissa? (I'm ignoring floating point numbers with non-zero exponents here.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is what he's asking...  I think he's looking for a solution that will tell him if a number can be represented EXACTLY in binary form.  For example, 33.3.. That's a number cannot be represented in binary, because it will go on forever, so depending on your FPU settings, it will be represented as something like "33.333333333333336".  So, it looks like his method will do the job.  I don't know of a better way off the top of my head.
\

Comment: That's true, except his method doesn't do the job. Because he's passing an already rounded number, and there isn't a way to tell if the number was rounded or if it is exact.

Comment: Ah yes...  Good catch...  Duh.. I totally skimmed right over that fact when looking at his code.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Given a number r it can be represented exactly with finite precision in base 2 iff r can be written as r = m/2^n, where m, n are integers, and n >= 0.

For example 1/7 doesn't have a finite binary expression, also 1/6 and 1/10 can't be written with a finite expression in base 2.

But 1/4+1/32+1/1024, have a finite expression in base.

PS: In general you can express a number r with finite digits in a base b iff r=m/b^n where m, n are integers an n >= 0.

PPS: As almost everybody has stated previously using a double as input is a bad idea, because you are loosing precision, and you will end up with a different number.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the general criticism of using a double...
For a general finite decimal, you can determine if it has a finite representation in binary with the following algorithm:

1. Extract the fraction part of the decimal *f*.
2. Determine *f* x 10<sup>*b*</sup> = *c*, where *b* and *c* are integers.
3. Determine 2<sup>*d*</sup> >= 10<sup>*b*</sup>, where *d* is an integer.
4. If *c* x 2<sup>*b*</sup> / 10<sup>*b*</sup> is an integer, then the decimal has a finite representation in binary. Otherwise, it doesn't.

You can generalize this to any two bases.

Comment: _d_ is introduced in step 3 but not subsequently used - should it not appear in step 4 (i.e. 2^d not 2^b )?

Comment: @Clifford It does not matter whether you use `b` or `d`, and `d` is unneeded. If you think in terms of prime factors, either is equivalent to testing whether `c` is divisible by `5**b`, which is the test that is actually needed.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan : I&#39;ll have to, as you say, think about that, but if that is the case step 3 serves no purpose, yet the answer has stood for 8 years.  The method is not well explained in any case. It was referenced in a recent question which is my only interest.

Comment: @Clifford Please take a look at my answer to the recent question, and see if you can find any problems or ways of explaining it more clearly.