# Explanation on determining if a decimal number has a finite representation in a base

Tags: binary, floating-point, numbers, precision, radix

When trying to find the answer I came across this and was wondering if this is true and why it is.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/489870/5712298

If anyone can explain it to me or link me to a page explaining it that would be great.

Comment: The answer you linked determines whether a decimal value can be represented exactly in _binary floating-point_, although the answer just says _binary_, which on its own is ambiguous.  As such the title of your question perhaps needs changing, it is very specific to  _floating point_ representations rather then just "_a base_".

Comment: I think there is an error in the method description at the link, see my comment added to it.

Answer (score 1):

Stackoverflow markup does not support mathematical notation well, and most readers of this will be programmers, so I am going to use common programming expression syntax:

```
* multiplication
^ exponentiation
/ division
x[i] Element i of an array x
== equality
PROD product
```

This deals with the question of whether, given a radix `r` terminating fraction `a/(r^n)`, there is a terminating radix `s` fraction `b/(s^m)` with exactly the same value, `a`, `b` integers, `r` and `s` positive integers, `n` and `m` non-negative integers.

`a/(r^n)==b/(s^m)` is equivalent to `b==a*(s^m)/(r^n)`. `a/(r^n)` is exactly equal to some radix `s` terminating fraction if, and only if, there exists a positive integer `m` such that `a*(s^m)/(r^n)` is an integer.

Consider the prime factorization of `r`, `PROD(p[i]^k[i])`. If, for some `i`, `p[i]^k[i]` is a term in the prime factorization of `r`, then `p[i]^(n*k[i])` is a term in the prime factorization of `r^n`.

`a*(s^m)/(r^n)` is an integer if, and only if, every `p[i]^(n*k[i])` in the prime factorization of `r^n` is also a factor of `a*(s^m)`

First suppose `p[i]` is also a factor of `s`. Then for sufficiently large `m`, `p[i]^(n*k[i])` is a factor of `s^m`.

Now suppose `p[i]` is not a factor of `s`. `p[i]^(n*k[i])` is a factor of `a*(s^m)` if, and only if, it is a factor of `a`.

The necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of a non-negative integer `m` such that `b==a*(s^m)/(r^n)` is an integer is that, for each `p[i]^k[i]` in the prime factorization of `r`, either `p[i]` is a factor of `s` or `p[i]^(n*k[i])` is a factor of `a`.

Applying this to the common case of `r=10` and `s=2`, the prime factorization of `r` is `(2^1)*(5^1)`. 2 is a factor of 2, so we can ignore it. 5 is not, so we need `5^n` to be a factor of `a`.

Consider some specific cases:

Decimal `0.1` is `1/10`, 5 is not factor of 1, so there is no exact binary fraction equivalent.

Decimal `0.625`, `625/(10^3)`. `5^3` is 125, which is a factor of 625, so there is an exact binary fraction equivalent. (It is binary 0.101).

The method in the referenced answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/489870/5712298 is equivalent to this for decimal to binary. It would need some work to extend to the general case, to allow for prime factors whose exponent is not 1.